# Select records with the same name and another field having two values

Tags: sql, group-by

Given a table of products that are available in different colors,

```
NAME  COLOR
----  -----
pen   red
pen   blue
pen   yellow
box   red
mic   red
tape  blue
```

How can I find the names of the products that are available in both `red` and `blue` (`pen`), and the names of products available in `red`, but not in `blue` (`box`, `mic`)?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/021a6/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like `group by` with `having` for these types of queries.

For both colors:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

For red but not blue:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The conditions in the `having` clause count the number of rows that match the condition (for each `name`).  So, `> 0` means that at least one row matched and `= 0` means that no row matched.